# get the grandson nodeValue when using XPath

Tags: php, curl, xpath, domdocument

I am looking for a way to retrieve a nodeValue of a grandson. I only have unambiguous access to "I have unambiguous access to this class" class as shown below. How do I do it?

```
<class="I have unambiguous access to this class">
- <class="childClass">
-- <class="grandsonClass">
```

///////

```
function curlGet($url){
    $ch = curl_init($url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array($url));

    $results = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
    return $results;
}


function returnXPathObject($item){
    $xmlPageDom = new DOMDocument();
    @$xmlPageDom->loadHTML($item);
    $xmlPageXPath = new DOMXPath($xmlPageDom);
    return $xmlPageXPath;
}

$examplePage = curlGet("www.example.com");
$exampleXPath = returnXPathObject($examplePage);

$rating = $exampleXPath->query("//span[@class='grandfather']"); // I can access this guy, but I want it's grandchild.

// get child of grandfather's child (grandson of grandfather)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do relative XPath query by passing the 'grandfather' `$rating` as the context element :

```
$query = "./span[@class='childClass']/span[@class='grandsonClass']";
$grandSon = $exampleXPath->query($query, $rating);
```